# Shoring up drainage culvert slope

Tags: drainage

I just bought a new house, and the drainage culvert out front along the road has several areas where the slope has collapsed, resulting in what looks like a miniature landslide landscape. What is the best way to shore this up to improve the aesthetics without causing drainage problems? [image: collapse zone 1]

[image: collapse zone 2]

Comment: What kind of soil is that?  If you don't know, look at your extension service's or soil conservation service's map of soil types for your location.

Answer (score 1):

Your pictures appear to show a steeply sloped section with erosion, a flat section, and another sloped section (without erosion.) If the flat section resulted from poor compaction of an original sloped profile that did not have the flat part, you may be able to simply fill that back in so the slope is not as steep. If you want to keep it in mown grass, that might be the best bet.

Otherwise, "rip-rap" or fairly large rocks are arguably the standard method of holding a steep drainage slope.

Comment: It's supposed to be sloped from the top of the eroded section to the bottom of the ditch.  Looking down the ditch along the intended flow of water,it's supposed to look like a V, with the sides at about 45 degrees, and relatively flat up to the inflection point.